# Ignore package which is not present in public npm registry while installing dependencies from package.json file

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json

I want to install my project's npm dependencies using it's package.json file.

So, i am running `npm install` command which should install all the dependencies mentioned in the package.json file.

Now, I want that if any package out of all the dependencies couldn't get installed due to any reason let's say that package is not public and hosted in someone's private npm registry whose access i don't have or any other reason, then the command `npm install` should not terminate with error instead i want to ignore such npm packages and continue on installing the rest of the dependencies

How to achieve this ? or Is this even feasible ?

PS : `npm install --silent` doesn't solve the above problem, because all it does is that it will not log the error on terminal. It doesn't solve the actual problem i.e continue on installing the other npm packages from package.json if any npm package is not found on registry